# Why are reflexives prohibited in partitive constructions?

Tags: syntax, english, semantics

In a partitive construction, reflexives do not usually occur:

> Julie and Bob are talking about the two of them/*themselves.

The following example is from COCA:

> The men, all of them, stared into their cups.

In the above sentence, the pronoun *them* refers to *the men*. Ideally, reflexives should be able to appear when anaphoric relations are formed. For what reason do the reflexives eschew partitive structures?
Thanks in advance for any comments or answers.

Comment: I don’t think they’re ungrammatical in partitives as such – just in this particular type of partitive. ‘All of themselves’ isn’t ungrammatical, but it is semantically different, meaning not ‘all member of the group <them>’ but rather ‘the full extent of each member of the group <them>’. _The men washed all of themselves_ is perfectly valid, meaning not ‘all the men washed themselves’ but ‘each of the men washed himself all over’.

Comment: Simple: Julie and Bob are talking about themselves. **Versus** Julie and Bob are talking about the two of them. two different meanings. The same goes for: The men, all of them, stared into their cups. **versus** The men themselves stared into their cups.

Comment: Thanks! @Janus Bahs Jacquet    I did not detect the difference of the meaning.

Comment: @Buffoon Consider that ‘all’ can mean two different things: it can refer to every member of a countable group (all the cars, all of them); or it can refer to the entirety of a non-countable entity (all the water, all of the time), similar to _whole_. When used with a reflexive, it automatically takes on the latter meaning, not the former, so “The men washed all of themselves” is similar to “I washed all of myself” – that is, not just the feet or the face, but the entire body, from head to toe.

Comment: @ Janus Bahs Jacquet Thanks for the helpful message! I now understand the latter meaning you pointed out!